# Romberg Integration: Eliminating error

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I made a program that estimates the integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ with Romberg's algorithm:

$$h_n = \frac{1}{2^n}(b-a)$$
$$R_{0,0} = h_1(f(a)+f(b)) $$
$$R_{n,0} = \frac{1}{2}R_{n-1,0}+h_n\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} f(a+(2k-1)h_n)$$
$$R_{n,m} = R_{n,m-1} + \frac{1}{4^m-1}(R_{n,m-1} - R_{n-1,m-1})$$
Where n represents pieces, and m represents extrapolation.

Using this algorithm as it is, I can only get the integral correct (at least for $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$) to about 4 decimal places. A way to make this more accurate would be to set the extrapolation and pieces count to crazy high, but that would take significant computational power. I found that the error of the approximation is:

$$O(h_n^{2m+2}) \ n \geq m, m\geq 1 $$

How do you find the integral, accurate to more decimal places using this error? How do you convert this big O notation to paper, or algorithm?

Comment: What is the function you are trying to integrate?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Currently, $e^{-x^2}$, but I would like to be able to integrate other functions too

Comment: BTW here's my own implementation of Romberg's method (for integrating the arc length of Bézier curves and elliptical arcs): https://github.com/Parclytaxel/Kinross/blob/master/kinback/algebra.py#L118

Comment: @ParclyTaxel What does e mean? I've seen numbers like 1e-18, and 1e-6 labeled as "Tolerance" in some programs, but I am unsure about the meaning of that

Comment: e is the tolerance; the difference between $R_{n,n}$ and $R_{n,n-1}$ must go below e for the algorithm to stop. Are you using this criterion?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I am not using Tolerance, because as mentioned, I didn't know what it was. Also, I anticipate that the "e" in 1e-18 is Euler's number, and not something else?

Comment: This is computer shorthand for "10 to the power of". 1e-18 = $10^{-18}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44951/discussion-between-thebro21-and-parcly-taxel).